# what do "All" and "Bot" mean in vim status line?

Tags: linux, unix, vim

and how can I print the blueprint of the statusline?

`set statusline?` prints blank (`statusline=`) which doesn't seem correct to me as my statusline shows filename, row and column numbers as well as "All" or "Bot" at the end.

Comment: `Bot` means you're at the bottom of the file (last line). All... depends on its position and your statusline configuration.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- **Bot** - **Bot**tom of file / last line is visible
- **All** - first and last line are visible
- **Top** - **Top** of file / first line is visible

Comment: thanks! shouldn't the name of these elements be printed with the command `set statusline?`

Comment: `:help statusline` shows the documentation while `set statusline?` just shows its current settings (not what the stuff means). These are actually documented in the `ruler` option (so `:help ruler`), which is kind of the default statusline if you don't have one set. I think :-S